# Send Excel File to Printer using Process.Start

Tags: c#, excel, printing

I want to send excel file to printer with c# console application. I tried something like this.

```
    public static void printExcel(string printpath)
    {

        string printerName = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
        {
            string pName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
            if (pName.Contains("PRINTER"))
            {
                printerName = pName;
                break;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(printpath); 
            info.Verb = "PrintTo";
            info.Arguments = printerName;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

    }
```

This console application will run like a batch. So it must be run without any prompt screen. But while app running i got some excel error. When i click "yes" excel sent to printer. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjGeL.png)
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does this problem occur when you load the file manually?  Perhaps you should fix that problem?

Comment: Yes, problem seems like version conflict. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its about excel's safe mode. if file comes from some other source maybe you should check. Can you try to check properties of xlsx file? it maybe blocked and maybe you need to release block.